# Android Kotlin coroutines create RecyclerView on fragment open with variable

Tags: android, database, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

As told in the title i try to create a recyclerview on fragment open with a variable.

Here is a working version without variable:
Fragment:

```
viewModel.lists.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
   listAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
val lists = shishaDao.getList(HARDCODED_INT).asLiveData()
```

As you can see, there is an hardcoded integer. This integer can hold different values, which is changing the lists value.

Here is my try with a variable:
Fragment:

```
viewModel.lists(title).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
   listAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

Instead of accessing a variable of the viewholder I am now wanna access a function, which needs the neccessary variable.

ViewHolder:

```
fun lists(title: String): LiveData<List<Tabak>> {
   val nr = dao.getNr(title)
   return dao.getList(nr).asLiveData()
}
```

The App is crashing with following error:

```
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Here are also tried ways:

```
fun lists(title: String): LiveData<List<Tabak>> {
   val nr: Int = 0
   viewModelScope.launch {
      nr = dao.getNr(title)
      Log.e("NR", nr.toString())
   }
   return dao.getList(nr).asLiveData()
}
```

```
fun lists(title: String): LiveData<List<Tabak>> {
   val nr: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(0)
   viewModelScope.launch {
      nr.value = dao.getNr(title)
      Log.e("NR", nr.value.toString())
   }
   return dao.getList(nr.value!!).asLiveData()
}
```

Both methods do not crash. The Log.e display the right number, but the last line still uses the 0.

My actual question: How can i get thi nr value from dao.getNr(title) to use it in the last line getList(nr)?

Comment: So what is your actual question? How to fix the "Cannot access database on the main thread"? This you can do with `lifeCycleScope.launch { nr = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { dao.getNr(title) } Log.e("NR", nr.toString()) }`

Comment: Hello Christian. I found a mistake. ``lifeCycleScope`` should be ``viewModelScope``. With that your solution does not help unfortunately. I updated my question, and added my question as well.

Comment: Does `dao.getNr` return a Flow? It should be fine to get a Flow reference or start observing a LiveData on the main thread, so I don't see how your code could produce that error. Please show your definition of the `getNr` function.

Comment: ``@Query("SELECT nr FROM titles WHERE title = :title")``
``suspend fun getNr(title: String): Int``

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found a way using LiveData. This is a big way, but a useful as well.

**new** PreferenceManager.kt

```
class PreferencesManager @Inject constructor(context: Context) {

    private val dataStore = context.createDataStore("user_preferences")

    val preferencesFlow = dataStore.data
        .catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error reading preferences", exception)
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
        }
        .map { preferences ->
            val choseMarke = preferences[PreferencesKeys.CHOSE_TITLE] ?: 2
            FilterPreference(choseTitle)
        }

    suspend fun updateChoseTitle (choseTitle: Int) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferencesKeys.CHOSE_TITLE] = choseTitle
        }
    }

    private object PreferencesKeys {
        val CHOSE_TITLE = preferencesKey<Int>("chosen_title")
    }
}
```

Fragment.kt looks again like this

```
viewModel.lists.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
   listAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

And the ViewModel.kt

```
class ListsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val dao: Dao, private val preferencesManager: PreferencesManager, @Assisted private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    val searchQuery = state.getLiveData("searchTitle", "")
    val preferencesFlow = preferencesManager.preferencesFlow

    ...

    private val listsFlow = combine(searchQuery.asFlow(), preferencesFlow) { query, filterPreference ->
        Pair(query, filterPreference)
    }.flatMapLatest { (_, filterPreference) ->
        dao.getList(filterPreference.choseMarke)
    }
```

I am not more trying to use the title inside of the fragment. Before opening the fragment, i need to press a button which this title, and then I already save the title (as int from the dao getNr) inside the mainActivity.

MainActivity.kt

```
onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
   viewModel.onNavigationClicked(item)
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
fun onNavigationClicked(item: MenuItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
   val choseMarkeNr = shishaDao.getMarkeNr(item.title.toString())
   preferencesManager.updateChoseMarke(choseMarkeNr)
}
```

This way is working. :)